# VBA To send an autoreply message to only domains outside organization

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to be able to select a bunch of emails and run the macro, and leave out a particular domain. How can I modify my code to NOT send the auto reply to people from a particular domain like "@domain.com"? Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplywithTemplate2()
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OutPut As Integer

For Each Item In ActiveExplorer.Selection

' This sends a response back using a template
Set oRespond = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Accounting\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\scautoreply.oft")

On Error Resume Next
    With oRespond
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Subpayables Invoices"
        .Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
        .Subject = Item.Subject 'use Item.Subject to keep the original subject

        ' use .display for testing, change to .send once you have it working as desired
        .Display
    End With

Next

OutPut = MsgBox("Successfully Completed the Task.", vbInformation, "Auto Reply From Template")

Set oRespond = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a test before adding recepients, so change `Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress` to :

```
If InStr(1, Item.SenderEmailAddress, "domain.com") > 0 Then
    'User from "@domain.com"
    'Do not respond
Else
    'Not a user from "@domain.com"
    .Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
End If
```